# Set colors to hue categories

Tags: colors, seaborn, histplot

I'm trying to use sns.histplot() with 'hue' but the colors of the legend and the bars does not match. I would like to change the colors of the bars(blue, dark blue) to another, maybe the same as the legend.

How can I do that?

Here what I tried and did not work.

```
colors = sns.color_palette()
sns.histplot(data=dataset, x='contract', hue='churn', color=colors[:2])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And here what I got

[image]

Comment: add `multiple='stack'` to the plot call. Your bars are currently layered with the orange below the blue, which kind of looks like dark blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two misunderstandings:

- `color=` is ignored when working with hue. Instead, seaborn has the [`palette=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) parameter, which is much more versatile. `palette` can be a name of colormap, a list of colors, or a dictionary.
- As mentioned by @TrentonMcKinney, by default the different hue values get layered transparently on top of each other (`multiple='layer'`).  `multiple='stack'` or multiple='dodge' will avoid overlapping bars. Further, you can set alpha=1 to get the full colors.

This is what happens by default when the x-values are discrete.  The bars are plotted transparently, and `color=` is ignored.

```py
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='class', hue='alive', color=['navy', 'cornflowerblue'])
```

[image: default histplot]

Colors can be set via a `palette`, e.g. `palette=['navy', 'cornflowerblue']`.  To make sure which hue value gets which color, the `palette` can be a dictionary. With `multiple='dodge'`, the bars are drawn next to each other. `shrink=0.8` adds some spacing between the bars.

```py
sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='class', hue='alive', multiple='dodge',
             palette={'no': 'navy', 'yes': 'cornflowerblue'}, shrink=0.8)
```

[image: sns.histplot with multiple='dodge']

`multiple='stack'` stacks the bars. `alpha=1` removes the transparency.

```py
sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='class', hue='alive', alpha=1, multiple='stack', shrink=0.8,
             palette={'no': 'navy', 'yes': 'cornflowerblue'})
```

[image: sns.histplot with multiple='stack']